# django rest framework update method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

should i use **is_valid()** function for validating my user data in **put()** function in drf?
because when i use it ,**is_valid.errors** says that model with this username and email is already exists!i can't understand the errors meaning,because i think should be something saved before i want to update

serializers.py

```
class UserCreateSerializers(ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('name','email','family',"username","password","profile_pic")

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    print("from update try")       

    #more dry  
    for i in validated_data.keys():
        if hasattr(instance,str(i)) and str(i) !="password":
            setattr(instance,str(i),validated_data.get(str(i)))

        elif hasattr(instance,str(i)) and str(i) =="password":
            instance.set_password(validated_data.get('password'))

    setattr(instance,"username",validated_data.get('new_username'))
    instance.save()
```

views.py

```
    def put(self,request):

    username = request.data['username']
    user = User.objects.get(username = username)
    serialized = UserCreateSerializers(data = request.data)

    if serialized.is_valid():
        serialized.update(user,serialized.validated_data)
        return Response(data ={"status":"api_user_update_ok"} , status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    else:
        print(serialized.errors)
        return Response(data = {"status":"api_user_update_failed","error":serialized.errors.get('email')[0]},status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

client data with put method :

```
name:user
family:useri
username:user2
password:1234
new_username:user22
email:user@gmail.com
```

error is :

> {'email': [ErrorDetail(string='user with this email already exists.',
>   code='unique')], 'username': [ErrorDetail(string='user with this
>   username already exists.', code='unique')]} Bad Request:
>   /api/v0/registration/signup

and the server response is :

```
{
    "status": "api_user_update_failed",
    "error": "user with this email already exists."
}
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes you should use `is_valid()` before try to save received data into DB. You see this error because DRF add uniqueness validator to unique fields by default. This behavior described in the [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#example).

To tell django that you are updating object and don't need uniqueness validator you have to provide instance to serializer:

```
serialized = UserCreateSerializers(user, data=request.data)
```

Comment: thanks @neverwalkaloner this is solve my issue similair to the one above, just a side effect, if we have nested objects under the serializer is there more general approach to solve the issue instead of applying the same approach for each nested object?